# IllegalStateException : migration from jboss 4 to jboss 5

Tags: java, ejb-3.0, jboss5.x

am migrating from jboss 4 to jboss 5. When i put the EAR in jboss-5 i get below exception. What would be the problem ?

The EAR is built in java 1.6.

Earlier it was deployed in jboss 4.2 and now the requirement is to migrate the same to jboss 5

while doing the same i get the below exception.

I checked all the jar files to see if nay bad-names, but everything is fine

```
org.jboss.deployers.spi.DeploymentException: Error during deploy: vfszip:/D:/softwares/jboss-5.1.0.GA/server/default/deploy/ssms.ear/common.jar/jaxb-xjc-2.1.6.jar/1.0/
        at org.jboss.deployers.spi.DeploymentException.rethrowAsDeploymentException(DeploymentException.java:49)
        at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployerWrapper.deploy(DeployerWrapper.java:177)
        at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.doDeploy(DeployersImpl.java:1439)
        at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.doInstallParentFirst(DeployersImpl.java:1157)
        at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.doInstallParentFirst(DeployersImpl.java:1210)
        at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.doInstallParentFirst(DeployersImpl.java:1210)
        at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.doInstallParentFirst(DeployersImpl.java:1210)
        at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.install(DeployersImpl.java:1098)
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContext.install(AbstractControllerContext.java:348)
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractController.java:1631)
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.incrementState(AbstractController.java:934)
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1082)
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:984)
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:822)
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:553)
        at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.process(DeployersImpl.java:781)
        at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.main.MainDeployerImpl.process(MainDeployerImpl.java:702)
        at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.repository.MainDeployerAdapter.process(MainDeployerAdapter.java:117)
        at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.repository.ProfileDeployAction.install(ProfileDeployAction.java:70)
        at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.repository.AbstractProfileAction.install(AbstractProfileAction.java:53)
        at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.repository.AbstractProfileService.install(AbstractProfileService.java:361)
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContext.install(AbstractControllerContext.java:348)
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractController.java:1631)
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.incrementState(AbstractController.java:934)
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1082)
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:984)
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:822)
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:553)
        at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.repository.AbstractProfileService.activateProfile(AbstractProfileService.java:306)
        at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.ProfileServiceBootstrap.start(ProfileServiceBootstrap.java:271)
        at org.jboss.bootstrap.AbstractServerImpl.start(AbstractServerImpl.java:461)
        at org.jboss.Main.boot(Main.java:221)
        at org.jboss.Main$1.run(Main.java:556)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected either '.jar' or '.jar/' at the end of 1.0
        at org.jboss.ejb3.deployers.Ejb3ClientDeployer.getDeploymentJndiName(Ejb3ClientDeployer.java:214)
        at org.jboss.ejb3.deployers.Ejb3ClientDeployer.deploy(Ejb3ClientDeployer.java:104)
        at org.jboss.ejb3.deployers.Ejb3ClientDeployer.deploy(Ejb3ClientDeployer.java:61)
        at org.jboss.deployers.vfs.spi.deployer.AbstractSimpleVFSRealDeployer.deploy(AbstractSimpleVFSRealDeployer.java:56)
        at org.jboss.deployers.spi.deployer.helpers.AbstractSimpleRealDeployer.internalDeploy(AbstractSimpleRealDeployer.java:62)
        at org.jboss.deployers.spi.deployer.helpers.AbstractRealDeployer.deploy(AbstractRealDeployer.java:50)
        at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployerWrapper.deploy(DeployerWrapper.java:171)
        ... 32 more
14:40:15,115 INFO  [JBossASKernel] Created KernelDeployment for: jaxb-xjc-2.1.6.jar
14:40:15,121 INFO  [JBossASKernel] installing bean: jboss.j2ee:ear=common.jar,jar=jaxb-xjc-2.1.6.jar,name=jaxb-xjc-2.1.6,service=EJB3
14:40:15,127 INFO  [JBossASKernel]   with dependencies:
14:40:15,130 INFO  [JBossASKernel]   and demands:
14:40:15,134 INFO  [JBossASKernel]   and supplies:
14:40:15,138 INFO  [JBossASKernel] Added bean(jboss.j2ee:ear=common.jar,jar=jaxb-xjc-2.1.6.jar,name=jaxb-xjc-2.1.6,service=EJB3) to KernelDeployment of: jaxb-xjc-2.1.6.jar
14:40:15,146 ERROR [AbstractKernelController] Error installing to Real: name=vfszip:/D:/softwares/jboss-5.1.0.GA/server/default/deploy/ssmscms.ear/ state=PreReal mode=Manual requiredState=Real
org.jboss.deployers.spi.DeploymentException: Error during deploy: vfszip:/D:/softwares/jboss-5.1.0.GA/server/default/deploy/ssmscms.ear/common.jar/jaxb-xjc-2.1.6.jar/1.0/
        at org.jboss.deployers.spi.DeploymentException.rethrowAsDeploymentException(DeploymentException.java:49)
        at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployerWrapper.deploy(DeployerWrapper.java:177)
        at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.doDeploy(DeployersImpl.java:1439)
        at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.doInstallParentFirst(DeployersImpl.java:1157)
        at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.doInstallParentFirst(DeployersImpl.java:1210)
        at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.doInstallParentFirst(DeployersImpl.java:1210)
        at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.doInstallParentFirst(DeployersImpl.java:1210)
        at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.install(DeployersImpl.java:1098)
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContext.install(AbstractControllerContext.java:348)
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractController.java:1631)
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.incrementState(AbstractController.java:934)
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1082)
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:984)
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:822)
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:553)
        at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.process(DeployersImpl.java:781)
        at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.main.MainDeployerImpl.process(MainDeployerImpl.java:702)
        at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.repository.MainDeployerAdapter.process(MainDeployerAdapter.java:117)
        at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.repository.ProfileDeployAction.install(ProfileDeployAction.java:70)
        at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.repository.AbstractProfileAction.install(AbstractProfileAction.java:53)
        at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.repository.AbstractProfileService.install(AbstractProfileService.java:361)
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContext.install(AbstractControllerContext.java:348)
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractController.java:1631)
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.incrementState(AbstractController.java:934)
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1082)
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:984)
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:822)
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:553)
        at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.repository.AbstractProfileService.activateProfile(AbstractProfileService.java:306)
        at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.ProfileServiceBootstrap.start(ProfileServiceBootstrap.java:271)
        at org.jboss.bootstrap.AbstractServerImpl.start(AbstractServerImpl.java:461)
        at org.jboss.Main.boot(Main.java:221)
        at org.jboss.Main$1.run(Main.java:556)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected either '.jar' or '.jar/' at the end of 1.0
        at org.jboss.ejb3.deployers.Ejb3ClientDeployer.getDeploymentJndiName(Ejb3ClientDeployer.java:214)
        at org.jboss.ejb3.deployers.Ejb3ClientDeployer.deploy(Ejb3ClientDeployer.java:104)
        at org.jboss.ejb3.deployers.Ejb3ClientDeployer.deploy(Ejb3ClientDeployer.java:61)
        at org.jboss.deployers.vfs.spi.deployer.AbstractSimpleVFSRealDeployer.deploy(AbstractSimpleVFSRealDeployer.java:56)
        at org.jboss.deployers.spi.deployer.helpers.AbstractSimpleRealDeployer.internalDeploy(AbstractSimpleRealDeployer.java:62)
        at org.jboss.deployers.spi.deployer.helpers.AbstractRealDeployer.deploy(AbstractRealDeployer.java:50)
        at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployerWrapper.deploy(DeployerWrapper.java:171)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Removed all jaxb related jar from local app and placed it in jboss's lib folder (if that lib is not there in jboss already). Also made sure that local app's lib folder contains only .jar file and not any other extensions